# Force on circular current loop in non-uniform magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetostatics

First off I'm not very good with the physics so if this is easy please excuse my ignorance.

The question is asking me to find force on a circular current loop with current I. It is placed in a magnetic field in the xy - plane centre at origin. Magnetic field $B = -x\hat{i}  -y \hat{j} + (1+3z)\hat{k}$.

I need to find the force on the loop. I know this is not a uniform magnetic field. Again not the most fluent in this topic.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, force on a current carrying conductor is given by
F=$\int I(dl×B)$
where dl is a small current element and B the magnetic field.
Both are vector quantities and must be multiplied vectorialy and integrated over concerned limits.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess the point is when it's nonuniform field it get's messy summing up each infinitesimal portion unless you can employ symmetry.